# How do I stop the fall through of element in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button(styled from a div tag, jquery UI) and a input text box inside. I want that if I click the text box the button won't get clicked also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your event handler for the `input` element:

```
$("input").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) stops the event from propagating up the DOM tree, which prevents parent event handlers of being notified of the event.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/J76Gw/

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can check inside the button's click handler whether `event.target` is the input field or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.stopPropagation();` for textbox click event.

Answer (score 0):

In the click handler for the input box you need to stop the click event propagating to the parent DOM element. So check out `event.stopPropagation()` - more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).