# having trouble collapsing these li without clicking the ul

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically creating a hierarchical list with this recursive function:

```php
function createFolderStructure($path, $root = true) {
    $html = '<ul' . ($root ? ' style="display:block;"' : '') . '>';

    // Get the list of files and directories in the current path
    $items = scandir($path);

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // Skip current and parent directory references
        if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        $itemPath = $path . '/' . $item;
        $isFolder = is_dir($itemPath);

        $html .= '<li onclick="toggleFolder(this)">' . $item;

        if ($isFolder) {
            // If it's a folder, recursively call the function to create child structure
            $html .= createFolderStructure($itemPath, false);
        }

        $html .= '</li>';
    }

    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}

// Set the root path to your images folder
$rootPath = 'users';

?>
```

This is the html/js/css that follows it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Folder Structure</title>
  <style>
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: none;
}

li {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px; /* Increase the padding to make the entire li area clickable */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
  <script>
    // Function to toggle visibility of the folder content
    function toggleFolder(element) {
      // Toggle visibility of the clicked folder content
      var ul = element.querySelector('ul');
      ul.style.display = ul.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="folderStructure">
 
 <?php echo createFolderStructure($rootPath); ?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So when I collapse the first folder, it does what it needs to do showing the child folder and its files, and so on. but it seems to be difficult to continue collapsing without accidently closing the parent folders.

I expect it to go down in hierarchical order and up in hierarchical order.  As it does, but for some reason as said the li and ul seem to stick when clicking the lower folders.

Comment: Relevant (potential dupes for anyone with a hammer): [Collapsing nested lists in a hiearchy-structure with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25968305/2943403) and [Dead simple Collapsable List Function for deep and shallow nested UL/LI lists (JQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31508500/2943403)

Comment: and [Parent collapses when expanding child using toggle and page scrolls to top](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49413779/2943403) and [jQuery: Stop dropdown menu from collapsing when clicking on its children](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13350809/2943403) and [How to prevent accordion from toggling when button in header is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24469602/2943403) and [How do I stop the fall through of element in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6724892/2943403)

Comment: That top structure is neither JavaScript nor HTML, so the tags are missing at least one language...

Comment: @Here I just removed the PHP and CSS tags because I felt they were irrelevant to the isolated problem.  Should the PHP tag be re-added?  You don't really need to understand PHP to understand/resolve this question, right?  If the asked question contained the static HTML (with no PHP), the [mcve] would be easier to reproduce and could actually enjoy stacksnippet formatting. I'd rather see the rendered HTML in the question instead of the dynamic PHP.

Comment: @mickmackusa I think that if the question contains PHP to such an extent, it should be tagged with the language. The formatting of PHP as JavaScript or HTML (as it does without the PHP tag to guide it) makes it difficult to read. I've added the formatting hint necessary to render the PHP correctly. I agree that the question would be better without the PHP at all.

Comment: We really need to see the rendered HTML and CSS, not the templating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling out to the container elements.

When creating the LI, pass the `event` to the `onclick` function:

```
        $html .= '<li onclick="toggleFolder(event)">' . $item;
```

Then use that in the function:

```
    // Function to toggle visibility of the folder content
    function toggleFolder(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      // Toggle visibility of the clicked folder content
      var ul = event.target.querySelector('ul');
      ul.style.display = ul.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
```